# Изменение прозрачности элемента

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно плавно менять прозрачность у элемента; в FF, CHROME, OPERA вроде меняется, а IE не хочет: он меняет только при присвоении стиля, а с помощью js не хочет, как сделать плавное изменение прозрачности в IE с помощью js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (ie) { // сами определяйте =)
  el.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity='+Math.round(opacity * 100)+')';
  } else el.style.opacity = opacity;
// el - элемент
// opacity - прозрачность (0..1)
```

[Статья на тему](http://www.tigir.com/opacity.htm)

Comment: Я извиняюсь, никак не хочет меняться...